# Why do my check marks render as ? in maven exec:java plugin?

Tags: java, maven, character-encoding

I am writing a little tester that writes a check or x to the console, depending on results.

It might look something like this `System.out.printf("%s%n", flag?"✓":"x");`

It works fine when I run it from my IDE. But when I run it from the maven exec:java plugin, it displays ? instead of ✓

I tried adding -DMAVEN_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" to the beginning of the command line, but no luck

Comment: That likely means that your terminal doesn't support/isn't using the character encoding that supports the ✓ character. In such a case, the terminal collates the unknown character to something different: '?' in this case.

Comment: Hmm, that was a great suggestion, but I am able to paste the check mark into the terminal, and it displays properly

Comment: Check the encoding of the Java file with `file MyFile.java` and the encoding used by the terminal with `echo $LC_CTYPE`.

Comment: How do you check that in Windows?